# CREATE_FAILED: IamRoleLambdaExecution (AWS::IAM::Role)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

How I fix this one.

Error:
[image: I am getting this error when deploy]

serverless.yml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: eu-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb.PutItem
      Resource: 
        - arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/AuctionsTable
```

I am new to aws services and serverless app development
when running `sls deploy` I am getting below error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in policy document, you used `.`(dot) in place of `:`(colon).

```yaml
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:PutItem # use `:` here instead of `.`
```